# Pass filename as variable in python during reading a file

Tags: python

I have an image file in the following location.

```
'D:\\projects\\Aielectric\\Bird\train_images\\BIRD_v200_1_1/IMG_2012-09-26T09-00-07.jpg'
```

While I am trying to read by directly giving the filename it reads the image properly.

**Working Code**

```
mm = cv2.imread( r'D:\\projects\\Aielectric\\Bird\train_images\\BIRD_v200_1_1/IMG_2012-09-26T09-00-07.jpg' )
```

But when I pass the path as variable, it is showing NoneType Object and is not reading the actual contents of file.

**Not working code**

```
tt = 'D:\\projects\\Aielectric\\Bird\train_images\\BIRD_v200_1_1/IMG_2012-09-26T09-00-07.jpg'

mm = cv2.imread( tt )
```

My requirement is to pass the name as a variable as it is not static. How to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't think you mean to have a raw string *and* the escaped backslashes (supposedly working code).

Comment: did you try `tt = r'your_path'`

Comment: Those two code fragments are not equivalent. Specifically the use of a raw string in the first.

Comment: @alani I meant how to read the file when filepath is sent as a variable name

Comment: You need to check what you are doing with the backslashes. And in all cases only a single backslash before "train" even where you *do* need to escape them - so it will be looking for a tab character.

Comment: There is no reason in principle why you can't put the string constant into a variable.

Comment: @jarmod How to modify it to change to this format : tt = r + image_dir + 'IMG_2012-09-26T09-00-07.jpg'

Comment: @SoumyaBoral You should use `os.path.join` in that case.

Comment: @alani mm = cv2.imread( os.path.join( image_dir, 'IMG_2012-09-26T09-00-07.jpg' ) ) still gives nonetype object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221176/discussion-between-soumya-boral-and-alani).

Comment: `/` works for windows paths in python, too, which avoids the escape-character problem altogether.

Comment: Use os.path.join as suggested by @alani and/or `Path` from `pathlib`: `tt = Path(os.path.join( _list_of_path_elements_here_ ))`